# Desktop menu to Fade In on mouse movement yet stay hidden in mobile screen size

Tags: javascript, mobile, menu, media-queries

I need a menu that fades in when either the mouse stops moving, or it leaves the browser window. I currently have the desktop menu hiding using css media queries. The problem is that when I execute this code, the desktop version (above 768px) shows up despite the media query. Any suggestions?

```js
 $(function() {
  
  var timer;

  $(window).on('mousemove', function () {
    $('.hide-for-video').addClass('show');
    try {
   clearTimeout(timer);
    } catch (e) {}
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
   $('.hide-for-video').removeClass('show');
    }, 1500);
  });
  
 });
```

```css
.hide-for-video {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease; }
.hide-for-video.show {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible; }

#menu {
  display: none;
 }
#menu-mobile {
  display: block;
 }



/* Larger Than 768px */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
 #menu {
  display: block;
 }
 #menu-mobile {
  display: none;
 }
 .hide-for-video.show {
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
 }
}
```

```html
<!--Desktop Menu 
===========================================-->
  
<nav id="menu" class="hide-for-video" >
</nav>


<!--Mobile Menu 
===========================================-->

<nav id="menu-mobile" class="" >
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(function() {

```
    var timer;
    if($(window).width() > 723){
    $(window).on('mousemove', function () {
      $('.hide-for-video').addClass('show');
      try {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      } catch (e) {}
      timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.hide-for-video').removeClass('show');
      }, 1500);
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: @A.Kolbo - Great, if I answered your question correctly please hit the checkmark by my answer :)